# Ошибка запрос mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
$data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test");
$row = $data->fetch_assoc();
foreach($row as $item) {
  echo $item['id'];
}
?>
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Warning: Illegal string offset
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
$data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test");

while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo $row['id'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: А возможно ли использование foreach?

Comment: нет, foreach проходит по уже готовому массиву, а fetch_assoc берет массив полей записи из стека